# Change line after add image in SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, spannablestring

I am adding 'xyz' text in `SpannableStringBuilder` I can change line at the time image add so image comes in next line but after added image, I want cursor position in next line so if I write any text after adding an image it should be come from next line.

```
int selectionCursor = mEdtComment.getSelectionStart();
    mEdtComment.getText().insert(selectionCursor, "\n" + ".");
    selectionCursor = mEdtComment.getSelectionStart();
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(mEdtComment.getText());
    builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(mRotateBitmap), selectionCursor - ".".length(), selectionCursor,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    mEdtComment.setText(builder);
    mEdtComment.setSelection(selectionCursor);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 mEdtComment.setSelection(selectionCursor);
```

replace above line with below line :

```
mEdtComment.setSelection(mEdtComment.getText().length());
```